# Modify existing AutoMapper type map (for unit testing)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper

I use the [AssertConfigurationIsValid](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation) method to unit test my mapping profile. To make it accept my mapping, I need to explicitly ignore unmapped destination properties. This pollutes my mapping code and makes it less readable. Since this is only needed for the unit test with AssertConfigurationIsValid to pass, I'd like to move the "ignoring" code to the same unit test.

Consider the following mapping code from some mapping profile class:

```
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
   // here goes some actual mapping code:
   .ForMember(dest => dest.DestMember, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceMember))
   // and then go the explicitly ignored unmapped dest members,
   // just for AssertConfigurationIsValid to pass:
   .ForMember(dest => dest.IgnoredMember, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I want to move the latter code to a unit test method, so it will look like the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMappingConfiguration()
{
  Mapper.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
  Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IgnoredMember, opt => opt.Ignore());
  Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(MyProfile.Name);
}
```

There is already the FindTypeMapFor method in the Mapper class, but I cannot find a good way to add ignored properties to the mapping. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you have so many Ignore's ?

Comment: I'm mapping to my view model, which contains the GUI related properties like IsSelected, IsReadonly, IsDirty, wchich I initialize just after mapping, if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to do what I wanted.
Here is the main class with an extension method to add an ignored property to an existing map:

```cs
  static class TypeMapExtensions
  {
    public static TypeMap<TSource, TDestination> AddIgnoredMember<TSource, TDestination>(
      this TypeMap<TSource, TDestination> typeMap, 
      Expression<Func<TDestination, object>> accessorExpression)
    {
      MemberInfo memberInfo = ReflectionHelper.FindProperty(accessorExpression);
      IMemberAccessor memberAccessor = memberInfo.ToMemberAccessor();
      var propertyMap = new PropertyMap(memberAccessor);
      propertyMap.Ignore();
      AddPropertyMap(typeMap.Map, propertyMap);
      return typeMap;
    }

    private static void AddPropertyMap(TypeMap typeMap, PropertyMap propertyMap)
    {
      typeMap.AddPropertyMap(propertyMap);
      if (typeMap.HasDerivedTypesToInclude())
      {
        IEnumerable<TypeMap> derivedMaps = GetDerivedMaps(typeMap);
        foreach (var derivedMap in derivedMaps)
          derivedMap.AddInheritedPropertyMap(propertyMap);
      }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TypeMap> GetDerivedMaps(TypeMap typeMap)
    {
      return Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().Where(
        map =>
          (map.Profile == typeMap.Profile) &&
          (typeMap.TypeHasBeenIncluded(map.SourceType, map.DestinationType)));
    }
  }
```

The class TypeMap is nothing more than a wrapper against the original TypeMap. The point of the generic version is to allow fluent syntax (see below).

ReflectionHelper class borrowed from the AutoMapper source code. It depends on five other classes from the AutoMapper.Internal namespace, so they were borrowed as well.

At the end, all this allows me to write the following code:

```cs
TypeMap<SourceType, DestinationType>.Get()
  .AddIgnoredMember(dest => dest.IgnoredMember)
  .AddIgnoredMember(dest => dest.AnotherIgnoredMember);
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you initially ignore all members then provide specific mappings for the properties you need? I've previously created an extension to help with this:

```cs
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest>
    IgnoreAllUnmapped<TSource, TDest>(
        this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> expression)
{
    expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
    return expression;
}
```

Then you can do something like

```cs
CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .IgnoreAllUnmapped()
    .ForMember(d => d.DestMember, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.SourceMember))
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. But doesn't it defeat the whole purpose of the AssertConfigurationIsValid check?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Adding properties to `SourceType` obviously wont affect the assert (validations are based on the destination), and mappings that don't have the `IgnoreAllUnmapped` directive also wont be affected. So you need to decide how important it is that you catch changes to `DestinationType` for the mappings that do have this directive. Alternatively if it is important, then you could argue that unit tests that check the behaviour of the application will pick up any issues.

Comment: One usage for the IgnoreAllUnmapped I can imagine, is to disable validation (by AssertConfigurationIsValid) for several types, while preserving it for the rest on the same profile.